# Write a function any(s1, s2) that returns the first location in the string s1 where any character in a string s2 occurs

Tags: c

```
/* Program to return first location in the string s1 where any charater in a string s2 occurs or -1 if s1 does not contain any character in s2 */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s1 [] = "This is fun";
    char s2 [] = "fin";
    int loc = theF(s1, s2);
    printf("%d", loc);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int theF(char s1 [], char s2 [])
{
    int i = 0;
    int loc = -1;
    while (s1[i] != '\0')
    {
        int j = 0;
        while (s2[j] != '\0')
        {
            if (s2[j] == s1[i])
            {
                loc = (int)s1[i];
                return loc;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return loc;
}
```

Write a function any(s1, s2) that returns
the first location in the string s1 where any
character in a string s2 occurs, or -1 if s1 does
not contain any character in s2.
For example, any("This is fun", "fin") returns
2, (‘f ’ occurs in position 8, ‘i’ occurs in 2, and
‘n’ in 10), while any("This is fun", "dead") returns
-1.

Directions ^^

Do you guys see any issues? It's returning 105 when it should be returning 8. I checked ascii table and that would have no correlation to 8 unfortunately D:

Comment: You are returning the character code at that position, not the position itself. Guess what character `105` represents.

Comment: You should be checking for the i and j combination where the characters match, not the letter `loc = (int)s1[i];` tells you that the letter 105 matches. 105 is `i`.

Comment: For reference, this ends up being quite close to the standard library function `strpbrk`.

Answer (score 2):

`loc = (int)s1[i];` doesn't return the location of the character, but the character value itself in ASCII. What you want to return instead is `i`, `loc = i;`

Answer (score 0):

So as stated in my comment and many others, you're returning the value of the character at which the characters match instead of the position (i/j). Fixed code below with some minor coding differences. While loops can get confusing in my opinion so using for loops to illustrate that it will loop until the full length of both strings seems much easier to read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int any(char s1 [], char s2 []);

int main(void){
    char s1 [] = "This is fun";
    char s2 [] = "fin";

    int loc = any(s1, s2);

    if ( loc == -1 ){ printf("No matching chars\n"); }
    else { printf("%d\n", loc); }

    return 0;
}

int any(char s1 [], char s2 []){

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++ ){
        for ( j = 0; j < strlen(s2); j++ ){
            if (s1[i] == s2[j]){
                return i; // i+1 depending on literal placement
                      //   vs zero indexed arrays
            }
        }
        j=0;
    }

    return -1;

}
```

As mentioned by [Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923896/steve-summit), this is exactly what the function [strpbrk()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strpbrk.htm) does. A simple implementation using it would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    const char s1[] = "This is fun";
    const char s2[] = "fin";
    char *ret;

    ret = strpbrk(s1, s2);
    if(ret){
        printf("First matching character: %c\n", *ret);
    } else { printf("No matching chars\n"); }

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a much clearer and simpler code from the previous one that I wrote.

so the logic is basically just to check for the first occurrence of the **wantbefindloc** characters inside **yourstring** and once found we return the location of the index j as it is the first match of the two characters.

If we loop over the whole characters and nothing already returned, this implies that no matching where found. Thus, we return -1

note that you do not need to update any of the indexes at all and no need to load header files but *stdio*

```
#include<stdio.h>

int any();

int main() 
{

    int loc;

    char yourstring[] = "This is fun";
    char wantbefindloc[] = "dead";

    loc = any(yourstring, wantbefindloc);
    printf("%d", loc);

    return 0;
}

int any(char s1[], char s2[]) 
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0 ; s2[i] != '\0'; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0 ; s1[j] != '\0'; j++) 
        {
            if (s1[j] == s2[i]) 
            {
                return j;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```